# How to clear Intent that started Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

At the beginning Activity is launched by an Intent and something  is done with this Intent.

When I change orientation of my Activity, it's reloaded again and Intent is passed to the Activity.

How can I clear that Intent to prevent Activity from using it again?

I've tried `setIntent(null)`, but with no result.

Comment: pixel should unaccept the clearly wrong answer and accept @dcg's instead. That would have saved me about an hour of work going down the wrong path. See Dianne Hackborn's post on how setIntent is a lie: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/vrLdM5mKeoY/ThkOonAbtloJ

Comment: See if this helps - stackoverflow.com/a/19820057/313042

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had similar problem. This helped me.
Maybe you have to also use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and add extra data to the bundle so inState is not null, not sure.

```
Intent activityIntent = null; // Subsequent times it's null

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle inState) {
    super.onCreate(inState);
    .
    .
    if (inState!=null) {
        /*Recreating activity with a saved state*/
    } else {
        /*Creating activity*/
        activityIntent = getIntent(); // First time through intent is used
        /*Get your Extra Intent data here. You will be capturing data on 1st creation. */
}
```

Comment: I have a similar approach below that also lets you retain selective arguments from the original intent.

Comment: This does not work for me when opening from the recent apps list after exiting the app by backing out. The app opens with a null Bundle but the previous intent.

Answer (score 13):

Do not use `setIntent(null)`. It seems that while it may work sometimes, under some conditions the original intent may come back.

<strike>Instead, call `setIntent()` with a simple intent that doesn't have an action, data or extras, such as `new Intent(Context, Class)`.</strike>

Indeed, the use of `setIntent()` was actually not a good API design decision in the first place. Instead, as dcg noted, be sure you only check your intent the first time, when your `savedInstanceState` is still null.

Comment: setIntent is just there to confuse you -- don't use it. See @dcg's answer instead. When an Activity is destroyed, the original intent that started the Activity is always re-used no matter what you do with setIntent. The original Intent is kept outside of the app entirely, in the ActivityManager, and setIntent has no effect on it. See Dianne Hackborn's post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/vrLdM5mKeoY/ThkOonAbtloJ

Comment: Thanks for the reference to that post, @JohnnyLambada! Updated the answer to avoid misleading people.

Comment: Checking that `savedInstanceState == null` is BRILLIANT!!! This helped me differentiate whether I was starting my MainActivity from the launcher or from an intent received by opening an email attachment. +1

Answer (score 4):

**In Kotlin : -**

If you want to clear intent then this is the best option for it.

```
intent.replaceExtras(Bundle())
intent.action = ""
intent.data = null
intent.flags = 0
```

Comment: Perhaps elaborate on why this is the best option.

Comment: According to me this is good option also i cannot find some other option for it. Because i want to clear broadcast data(in run time) then i use this code. any my issue resolve.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the intent action, you can clear it with `getIntent().setAction("");`

For example in `onCreate(...)`:

```
...
String action = getIntent().getAction();
if (action != null) {
  if (action.equals(YOUR_ACTION_WHATEVER)) {
    doSomethingHere(); // do something here
    getIntent().setAction(""); // clear the action
  }
}
...
```

This will clear the action, otherwise it will be called every time you rotate the device.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is sent to your activity with an action (with setAction), just do the following when you receive the intent, to avoid multiple handling of this intent when screen rotates :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.setAction(null);
setIntent(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but some one could use this.

Dont waste time, if your app is resumed, the intent will be there again.

Use the starting intent on the "Activity Resume", and just add an extra value

```
putExtra("DONE", 0)
```

And each time your app resumes, check if already has this value:

```
hasExtra("DONE")
```

easy

Comment: It's not working. I think Android saves the `Intent` in a different way, not in the memory. You're only adding this value at runtime. When the activity is killed, the system retrieves the original `Intent` again.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to toggle this with a boolean variable to check wheather your activity is first created or not.

Otherwise you can look at your onCreate method, afaik this is only executed, when the activity is first created.

Comment: Agreed. Use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to pass the state from the old activity to the new one.

Comment: Actually onCreate() would also be called any time your screen orientation changes (the app is basically destroyed and re-created during this).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to set the data to null:

```
getIntent().setData(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`intent.putExtra(YourKey,""); //reset the value to knknown
setIntent(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Even after manually clearing the Intent and Intent extras after they have been parsed, it seems as though Activity.getIntent() will always return the original Intent that started the Activity.

To get around this, I recommend something like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // The Intent provided by getIntent() (and its extras) will persist through a restore
    // via savedInstance.  Because of this, restoring this activity from a
    // an instance that was originally started with extras (deep-link or 
    // pre-defined destination) may cause un-desired behavior
    // (ie...infinite loop of sending the user directly to somewhere else because of a
    // pre-defined alternate destination in the Intent's extras).
    //
    // To get around this, if restoring from savedInstanceState, we explicitly
    // set a new Intent *** to override the original Intent that started the activity.***
    // Note...it is still possible to re-use the original Intent values...simply
    // set them in the savedInstanceState Bundle in onSavedInstanceState.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Place savedInstanceState Bundle as the Intent "extras"
        setIntent(new Intent().putExtras(savedInstanceState));
    }

    processIntent(getIntent())
}

private void processIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
        // Protection condition
        return;
    }

    doSomething(intent.getExtras.getString("SOMETHING_I_REALLY_NEED_TO_PERSIST"));

    final String somethingIDontWantToPersist = 
        intent.getExtras.getString("SOMETHING_I_DONT_WANT_TO_PERSIST");

    if(somethingIDontWantToPersist != null) {
        doSomething(somethingIDontWantToPersist);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save selective extras from original Intent...
    savedInstanceState.putString("SOMETHING_I_REALLY_NEED_TO_PERSIST", "persistedValued");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

This way, there is a mechanism to dump the original Intent while still retaining the ability to explicitly retain certain parts of the original Intent / Intent extras.

Note that I haven't tested all Activity launch modes.