# Android intent reception and rotation

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, intentfilter

I'm using an Intent Filter in my activity to retrive an url clicked on by the user.

In my activity onCreate method I have the following code

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        url = intent.getDataString();
        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);          
    }
```

It works great except when I rotate my phone. Even if tha dialog was closed prior to the rotation, it reopen every time I change the phone orientation.
I can I avoir that.

For your information I don't want to lock the orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple fix. In you manifest file, locate activity and add this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

This will prevent your logic in onCreate to fire again (or so I believe)

Quoted [from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges):

> In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your
>   activity based on one or more types of configuration changes. This is
>   done with the android:configChanges attribute in its manifest. For any
>   types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will
>   receive a call to your current activity's
>   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) method instead of being
>   restarted. If a configuration change involves any that you do not
>   handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and
>   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) will not be called.

Comment: As I specify in my answer I don't want to do that. There must be a cleaner way

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaner"? Android:configChanges is specifically designed to handle situations where you don't want to re-run your onCreate logic. The alternative is to put some if elses into onCreate trying to exclude some code parts from executing based on say layout at time of onCreate call. BTW - this does not freeze the orientation to portret only - that's different configuration, namely android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: Is there a way to clear/consume the intent ?
I tried to do a SetIntent(null), before closing my dialog, but after rotation getIntent() is still returning the received intent...

Comment: @user1026605 I think you are misunderstanding Bostone's answer. This will not lock the orientation. The user will still be able to rotate the device. This will simply make it so that your Activity is not re-Created upon rotations

Comment: yes I understand, your point. It's working, but I still wonder if there is a different way to avoid the intent beegin fired twice without @Bostone solution.

Comment: Surely there are more ways. That is probably the easiest. You could probably achieve it somehow with a boolean flag and using a check to see if you need to show the dialog based on whether onCreate was result of orientation change or not.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding comes from the "consuming event" notion. If you are talking about the Intent which you get from getIntent() it's not "consumed" but is kept for the lifetime of Activity and you can access it pretty much anywhere in Activity code as long as Activity is not destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that doesn't require handling configuration changes yourself might be to simply check if the savedInstanceState Bundle parameter in onCreate is null before showing the dialog.

If you look at the docs for onCreate you can see that savedInstanceState will be non-null when the activity is recreated (due to configuration changes for example) and thus will be null when the activity is run fresh.

Answer (score 3):

You would typically call `setIntent(null)` to remove the intent used to summon the activity. However, in practice, it doesn't always work. Apparently, [a common workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148418/how-to-clear-intent-that-started-activity) is to set the intent's action or data or both to null, depending on what you use in code. In your case, after showing the dialog, I would probably go with `intent.setAction(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this issue until today. I did `getIntent().setAction("");`, and solved it. No more brain damage :)